# Trouble with removing and re-indexing array

Tags: php, mysql

I have three arrays which are related as follows:

```
$array1 = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
$array2 = array('item1value', 'item2value', 'item3value');
$array3 = array('item1quantity', 'item2quantity', 'item3quantity');
```

Sometimes, I need to remove a particular positioned key in an array, so that same positioned key has to be removed in remaining array's. I have tried following the logic:

```
unset($array1[0]);
array_values($array1);
unset($array2[0]);
array_values($array2);
unset($array3[0]);
array_values($array3);
```

Instead of the array_values() I tried array_shift(), and the following procedure also:

```
array_splice($array1[0]);
array_push( $cart1, 'itemnumber');
array_splice($array2[0]);
array_push($array2, 'itemvalue');
array_splice($array3[0]);
array_push($array3, 'itemqty');
```

Elements are removing perfectly in all the above algorithms, but the index order is jumbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually save/store the re-indexed array. Do this instead:

```
unset($array1[0]);
$array1 = array_values($array1);
unset($array2[0]);
$array2 = array_values($array2);
unset($array3[0]);
$array3 = array_values($array3);
```

Comment: i tried that one too, i already mentioned that. The problem is when i'm removing items from the cart i can see the $array2 values are jumbled. So i tried, array_shift, array_values both. Can you suggest me another way ?

Comment: @Venkat, are you sure you reassigned the values back? You seem to be doing `array_values($array1)`, whereas Ed is doing `$array1 = array_values($array1)`. The function `array_values()` does not modify the array you supply as a parameter - you need to capture the return value.

Comment: yes i tried. when we are unsetting array index the index is still there. so suppose i want to remove index 2 in all 3 array's, after removing 2nd indexes the 3 index and afterwards has to be continue from 2nd one.

Comment: So you have 3 arrays that need to be in sync at all times. Imo it would make more sense to create a single array that holds arrays with descriptive keys: `array(array('item' => 'item1', 'quantity' => 'item1quantity', 'value' => 'item1value'), array('item' => 'item2', 'quantity' => 'item2quantity', 'value' => 'item2value'))`.

Comment: @Arjan yeah ! its the actual procedure, i noticed everyone is suggesting this as you did, but i tried in this way to check it would work or not! thank you i will stick to the mentioned strategy.

Comment: @arjan i have tried that. Now i'm stuck with another state. I have an array, $array = array( array(1, 100, 1), array(2, 150, 1), array(3, 200, 1) ); now i want to check if item 2 existed in $array simply like in_array(). Is it possible ?